# NodeMediaServer - Manipulate video stream

Tags: node.js, node-media-server

i would like to know if its possible to manipulate/proccess the video stream inside the node media server itself.

I have an ai model that takes frame, and return edited frame. i would like to apply real time video proccessing for the streamers. im currently using node-media-server.

I would love to know if it's possible, and if yes how can i proccess the frames through my ai model?

Thanks!!

```
const NodeMediaServer = require("node-media-server");

const httpConfig = {
  port: 8000,
  allow_origin: "*",
  mediaroot: "./media",
};

const rtmpConfig = {
  port: 1935,
  chunk_size: 60000,
  gop_cache: true,
  ping: 10,
  ping_timeout: 60,
};

const transformationConfig = {
  ffmpeg: "./ffmpeg.exe",
  tasks: [
    {
      app: "livetest",
      hls: true,
      hlsFlags: "[hls_time=2:hls_list_size=3:hls_flags=delete_segments]",
      hlsKeep: false,
    },
  ],
  MediaRoot: "./media",
};

const config = {
  http: httpConfig,
  rtmp: rtmpConfig,
  trans: transformationConfig,
};

const nms = new NodeMediaServer(config);
nms.run();
```

I have tried adding
nms.on("prePublish" ...
but without anyhelp!